# Can a Verizon iPad (4th Gen) be used on AT&T GSM/HSPA+?

Tags: ipad

I have seen a lot of old information about this, but nothing new or recent.

I have a Verizon iPad (4th Generation) running iOS7 and want to switch to AT&T.

Can I drop an AT&T SIM in and run on AT&T's network (obviously sans LTE)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. It's unlocked, and you can move to any carrier you wish to. Of course, if you're planning to move off of Verizon, you would have to consider the terms dictated by your contract with Verizon.

Read more on [Are iPad Models Unlocked? - iPad Q&A (from EveryiPad.com)](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/ipad/ipad-faq/differences-between-ipad-4th-gen-late-2012-models.html). Here's a relevant quote:

> However, both of the iPad 4th Gen models with cellular data capability are sold "unlocked" and are capable of running on any compatible network.

Also, a footnote [Apple's LTE page](https://www.apple.com/ipad/LTE/) states (with emphasis here):

> 2. To identify your iPad model number, see http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5452. *iPad models are unlocked and may support LTE networks outside the country of purchase when using a valid SIM from a supported carrier. Contact your carrier for more details.*

Comment: Thanks!  I did it.  It pulled down the carrier settings after the AT&T SIM was activated and works like magic.  It's only GSM/HSPA+ (no LTE due to different bands between AT&T and VZW), but it's fast enough for what I need.

Comment: Of note, my VZW iPad is locked from being able to do Facetime over Cellular and acting as a personal hotspot on AT&T's network.  Multiple interactions with support have provided no value of yet.

Answer (score 0):

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4745210?start=0&tstart=0

I googled this and found the two links in the answer. The top one basically says that you can drop any SIM card in because ipads are unlocked, and you'll have to change some carrier settings (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1970?viewlocale=en_US)

Comment: I didn't have to change any carrier settings; plopping in the AT&T SIM forced an APN update and pulled down all the necessary AT&T settings like magic.

Comment: That's good. I didn't know that it forced it.

Answer (score 0):

I got an AT&T sim today for an iPad air Verizon and it worked with AT&T LTE. Compared speeds in the iPad Air 2 using the AT&T sim and they were equal. Back of my iPad Air box says it supports CDMA, GSM and a few other networks.

To respond to a previous it is not forcing me to use 3G speeds using the AT&T sim on a Verizon iPad Air.

Comment: The iPad Air was specifically designed to work on multiple carriers.  The 4th Gen iPad was not, so unfortunately it's an apples-to-oranges (get it?) comparison.  :-(